# Would centaurs HAVE to cook meat?

Tags: biology, mythology, centaur

The way I depict centaurs are like very wild people like Tarzan - living in the wild with no clothes equipment, hunting with their hands and hooves. I'm wondering though if a centaur could eat raw meat. Most animals can but I'm not so sure about a half human. What do you guys think?

Comment: *Humans* can eat raw meat; and they actually do, e.g., [steak tartare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steak_tartare). Not to mention the large variety of popular meat products which are [dried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dried_meat) or [smoked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoked_meat), not cooked. [Sushi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi) is often made with raw fish; and fish is very commonly eaten dried or smoked and not cooked.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the closure as duplicate of [Would a centaur eat meat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/18371/29).That question focuses on whether centaurs would eat meat at all, whereas this question seems to posit centaurs that do eat meat and is asking whether they would need to cook it. Related, yes. Duplicate, I'm not at all so sure.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, while most animals CAN eat raw meat, as most are herbivores it's not always ideal as a food source, especially if not fresh. Horses in particular are herbivores (but have been documented as eating meat previously). Humans have evolved from herbivorous animals and by cooking meat in particular, we break down the proteins so that our stomachs can better handle the food. Even cooking things like potatoes maximises calorie intake for humans. This is the important point; cooking any food makes it easier to digest and extract the energy and nutrients from it, regardless of whether it is meat or vegetable.

So, if your centaur has a hybrid human / horse digestive tract (this is by no means certain) *and* that species can digest meat, it's almost certain that it would be beneficial to cook it. That said, some vegetables may be more readily digested without cooking. The interesting question would be whether or not your centaur could digest grass. Humans can't, but it's the principal food source for horses.

Ironically enough, Centaurs with a largely human digestive tract may well not have any concerns with appendicitis. The reason for this is that it is thought that the appendix is an atrophied organ that helped primates process vegetable matter more effectively. The appendix in your centaur would probably be restored to its original purpose meaning that the organ is no longer redundant and therefore less likely to become aggravated or inflamed.